# SNMP traps for RF systems: where to start?

Tags: snmp

I've been given the task of taking various status bits from an embedded RF device and asked to turn them into SNMP Traps. I have the SNMP library but I lack the knowledge on where to get or create the OIDs. Here's an snmptrap as a point of reference:

```
  snmptrap -v 2c -c public 192.168.1.1:162 \
    .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 \
    ifIndex i 2 ifAdminStatus i 1 ifOperStatus i 1
```

Normally I'm on the receiving end of these traps and rely on the manufacturer-provided MIBs. So I'd get .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3 from the MIB file and add the necessary parameters to send.  Now, I think I'm the guy creating the MIBs. How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start by following the instructions from Net SNMP:

http://net-snmp.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Writing_your_own_MIBs

Comment: Wow, the answer is spot on and afraid to say that I should have tried to look for something as simple as this. :-)

Comment: Yes that page is well-written, short, and has very good links to what you need to get going.  Glad to have helped point you at it.

Comment: We're using an RTU to supply the SNMP interface, so tjis project has been put aside. But one of the recommendations was to purchase the book: Understanding SNMP MIBS by David Perkins and Even McGinnis. I'm using this book and the RTU's MIB to understand how MIBs relate to the device. So far I've learned quite a bit. Still have a ways to go yet. Thanks